# CKEditor, Ruby on rails, carrierwave, how to upload image from computer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ckeditor, carrierwave

How can I make this possible? I know that i have to do

```
config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl
```

on `/ckeditor/config.js`, here I have the following line:

```
config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '/app/uploaders/ckeditor_picture_uploader';
```

Here is my uploader file

```
class CkeditorPictureContentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include Ckeditor::Backend::CarrierWave
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/ckeditor/content/#{model.id}"
  end


  def extension_white_list
    Ckeditor.image_file_types
  end

end
```

It keeps marking **routes error** everytime I try to upload an image, I know that it must be something with the format of uploading but I don't what it is.